# Restrict sftp user to a single directory in El Capitan

Tags: macos, ssh

Searched the web for quite some time and still can't find a solution.

Is it even possible at all to restrict ssh user to a single directory in 10.11? I have set up an user account via System Preferences Users & Groups. Under Advanced Options I specified a home directory. This is the highest level directory he can go.

Followed some instruction to modify ssh/sshd_config to include:

```
Match User ftpuser
  ChrootDirectory <the directory path>
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the `<the directory path>` fulfils the next requirement specified in the manual pages for [`sshd_config(8)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

> All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.

If you don't, then

> it doesn't work.

But you are certainly notified about the problem in system log.