# Restricting remote user to a single directory in 10.11

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp

I need to confine remotely logged in users to stay in 1 directory only, so 
I would thought I should attack this problem via SFTP or SSH, so I asked in

[Restrict sftp user to a single directory in El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223721/restrict-sftp-user-to-a-single-directory-in-el-capitan).

But since `sshd_config` requires each component in the directory path must be owned by root, this requirement is not even possible in our case. So I guess both SSH and SFTP are not the solution.

What other approach can I take to do this task?

PS: After further reading, I think `/bin/bash -r` might be the way forward. Not sure if I can set up `ssh` to load `/sh/bash -r` by default.

PS: Tried to specify `/bin/bash -r` in Login Shell field within the user's Advanced Options in Users & Groups. Now the user cannot even login; password prompt keeps returning. In `system.log`, I get

```
PAM: authentication error for illegal user
```

Removing the `-r` option then the user can log in. I think a bit more config in `sshd_config` or `/etc/pam.d/sshd` will do the job....

Comment: You can try to add `/bin/rbash` as a shell for a user. It might help, since the previous one might got parsed wrong. But I don't think that `sftp` would work under these settings (maybe `internal-sftp`?), but for `ssh` it might be a partial solution. And by the way, to understand the importance of requirements "root owned", you should check [CVE-2009-2904](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2009-2904)

Comment: In OS X there's no rbash shell.... When I looked up man page for bash, it says to use -r for restricted. Ummm... May be I can alias "/bin/bash -r" and trigger it instead?

Comment: Yes. It is worth trying.

Comment: Tried it. I got:            /rbash.sh Exec format error                    Gotta give up.

Comment: Please, post exactly what you put into the  file and to the user.

Comment: In /rbash.sh, i put "/bin/bash -r", no quotes. Nothing to the user as he can log in normally and use bash. Once logged in, I ran /rbash.sh, and I really got a restricted bash; can't cd.

Comment: you should not forget about Shebang: `#!/bin/bash` or so on the first line, and the second line should inherit the arguments like `exec /bin/bash -r "$@"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file `/bin/rbash`, make it executable and and set it as a shell for this newly created user:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /bin/bash -r "$@"
```

The user over `ssh` is limited as manual page for bash describes in  "RESTRICTED SHELL" section.

Comment: Most importantly, "exit"'ing after logging into the restricted bash won't jump to a non-restricted bash! It disconnects completely! Yeah!

Comment: I tried it without the exit in the third line.

Comment: The third line should never get executed, since the `bash -r` get `exec`-ed. Or what did you mean by your first comment?

Comment: I have no knowledge of how OS X loads /rbash.... I thought, may be OSX loads the proper /bin/bash first then load /rbash. If so, even tho I have a restricted bash at the end, typing "exit" might bring me back to /bin/bash, which makes this whole exercise pointless. However I was proven wrong; OSX loads /rbash directly!

Comment: *nix way is as you wrote, but using `exec`, the original `bash` is "replaced" by `rbash` and there is no way to "return" back to the non-restricted `bash`.